# Infragistics -- UltraWebGrid, data binding

Tags: asp.net, dataset, infragistics, ultrawebgrid

```
         DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        int x = ddlSelectedValue.IndexOf('-');
        if (x > -1)
        ds = Selections.GetUnlinkedAccounts(clientID, AccountNo);

        else
            ds = Selections.GetAccountBasedAnnuity(clientID, AccountNo);

        AnnuityDetails.DataSource = ds;
        AnnuityDetails.DataBind();
```

AnnuityDetails is the Ultrawebgrid infragistics control, i am getting the dataset in to ds but the dataset is not binding into the WEbgrid..plz help me wth this

Answer (score 1):

Did you have generated the columns with IsBoubd property to true? This may cause this issue.